# How to authenticate user using custom model in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I am working on a Django project. The project has three pages Home, login, registration. Home page's nav bar has three buttons Home, login and registration. I have created a custom model I don't want to admin model. I already did the login part but now I want is after login the home nav login and register button disappear and a new button/text appear Hello user or whatever the name whoever is logged in.
Is there any way to do it I know we can do it with the admin User model but I don't know how to do it with a custom model?

**models.py**

```py
class  user_detail(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(("email"), max_length=254)
    first_name = models.CharField( ("first name"),max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(("last name"), max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(("address"), max_length=50)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(("phone number"))
    password = models.CharField(("password"), max_length=50)
```

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .models import user_detail

class loginView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'accounts/login.html'

    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print(request)
            html_email = request.POST['email']
            html_password = request.POST['password']

        user = user_detail.objects.values_list('email',flat = True)
        if html_email in list(user):
            user_password = user_detail.objects.filter(email = html_email).values_list('password',flat = True)[0]
            print(user_password)

            if user_password == html_password :
                return redirect('/home/')
        else:
            print(" incorrect credentials ")

        return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')
```

Edit: what I need is whenever some is logged in login/register button disappear and welcome ,+ first_name .

Comment: Why would that be different with a custom user model?

Comment: Lets say my model have username. Email, name, address, contact , role , profile_photo , and  password .I want to login using email .so I created new Model named "User_detail" and what I did for login is first it will check if email is present in db or nor if its present it will take password and compare it input password after that it will redirect to home page  authenticate() is not working with my "user_detail" model

Comment: can you edit the question with your model, register an login view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to having a custom user model is that to use AbstractUser.
you should do it like this:

```
Class User(AbstractUser):
    # add your custom field here
    birth_date=models.IntegerField()
```